# AVCaptureSession disappears / destroyed after going to use another app, and then returning to the original app

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, avfoundation, avcapturesession, dealloc

I have a `View Controller` that sets up and runs an `AVCaptureSession`. After the user captures a photo, I do some `Core Graphics` processing on the image to get the image ready for saving and uploading to third party services.

Because this `Core Graphics` processing takes some time, I decided to sort of "trick" the user when they press the button to capture a photo.

Instead of waiting for the `Core Graphics` processing to show their final photo on the screen, I just pause the `AVCaptureSession` and then it's `Preview Layer` just shows a freeze frame of what was on screen when the user pressed the button.

This has always worked perfectly for me, but now I have a problem.

When a user wants to share the final photo to Instagram, the Instagram app is opened and the user leaves my app. Once the user is done with the Instagram app and they come back to my app, the screen is just white, and I'm assuming this is because the `AVCaptureSession` and/or the objects that it interacts with are being destroyed.

The thing is, the user can still come back and share the final photo to other services just fine, but the average user won't even try to do that because the "photo"(paused `Preview Layer`) is not on screen anymore and they will just think that it has been deleted.

Is there a way that I can keep these `AVCaptureSession` objects from being destroyed, so that when the user comes back to my app it does not look like their photo has been erased from the screen?

Comment: Can't you capture the contents of the layer and display them instead? That way, your app wouldn't have to depend on the life cycle of `AVCaptureSession`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to make it depend on the life cycle of AVCaptureSession.

Comment: Well, as you saw yourself, you cannot rely on it as it will be destroyed when the app switches.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for a solution that could do that. Still not a master of memory management :)

Comment: If anyone else comes across this.. I ended up doing the following: 1. Register for notification in VC 2. Set the notification observer's selector to set your new image as the one on screen 3. Post notification in applicationWillResignActive when switching to different app. 4. When your user comes back to your app the new image will be set. It's not perfect and some users might notice a difference but most will probably not notice.